# Quando eu executo meu código ele apresenta o seguinte erro: TypeError: Dispatch() missing 1 required positional argument: 'dispatch'

Tags: python, email

```
import win32com.client as win32

**oulook = win32.Dispatch()**

# Integração com Outlook
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')

#Email

email = outlook.CreateItem(0)

#Configurar informações de email

email.To = "andrethomezinho@gmail.com"
email.Subject = "assunto"
email.HTMLBody = """<p>Olá André, eu so o Python kkkj</p>"""

email.Send()
print('Email enviado')
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

Ao que me parece, está faltando o argumento dispatch nessa linha:

```
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application', dispatch="<aqui vai o dispatch>")
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).